# Spyder is not launching from Anaconda Navigator, on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

While launching Spyder from Anaconda Navigator or directly from the menu, it is showing the given error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\Users\charchil\anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 6, in 
    from spyder.app.start import main 
  File "C:\Users\charchil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 22, in 
    import zmq 
  File "C:\Users\charchil\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq_init_.py", line 47, in 
    from zmq import backend 
  File "C:\Users\charchil\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend_init_.py", line 40, in 
    reraise(*exc_info) 
  File "C:\Users\charchil\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in 
    reraise raise value 
  File "C:\Users\charchil\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend_init_.py", line 27, in 
    ns = select_backend(first) 
  File "C:\Users\charchil\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in 
    select_backend mod = import(name, fromlist=public_api) 
  File "C:\Users\charchil\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython_init.py", line 6, in 
    from . import (constants, error, message, context, 
  ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from 'zmq.backend.cython' (C:\Users\charchil\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython_init_.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue was raised on [Jupyter Notebooks GitHub](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3435) so it seems likely that a similar solution will help you, i.e.:

Attempt:

```
conda uninstall pyzmq
conda install pyzmq
```

Using the conda packages should make sure that version compatibility is maintained. If, however, that still doesn't work (and some comments in the attached issue suggested that it didn't work for some people), attempt:

```
pip uninstall pyzmq
pip install pyzmq
```

You can check your version of pip with `pip --version` and might want to consider upgrading it first if it is a long way behind. Current version is 20.1.1. Command to upgrade pip is:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the Anaconda prompt

conda deactivate
conda update anaconda-navigator

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/update-navigator/

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still looking for a quicker answer then below solution might help you as well and this worked for me like a charm.

1. Open **Anaconda Prompt**
2. Run the command `conda update --all`
3. Re launch the **Anaconda Navigator** now
4. Now Launch, **spyder** or **jupyter notebook**. Probably it should work for you as well.

***NOTE:*** *If you are running any firewall application then, make sure you launch navigator in administrator mode and unblock any prompt requests accordingly for smooth launching. This is on windows systems again and may be a different way for other platforms.*

Hope this helps someone in need again. All the best.